How to get get already selected values from firebase firestore
I'm trying to create a reservation system when a user inputs their details, it is stored in Firebase Firestore with the date as the document ID. I'm trying to get the times that have been already selected and filter them out from the available times other users can choose from to prevent different users from selecting the same time on a particular date.
This is a demo of what I  want to do Vue Playground
I've gone through the documentation but still can't figure it out. The closest I got was that all the times selected on different dates were being filtered out but I want it to be filtered out only for specific dates users have already booked times.
this is the code which filters out all the times from every date at once
async function fetchBookedTimes() {
  const bookedTimesRef = collection(db, 'reservations')
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(bookedTimesRef)
  const bookedTimesArray = []
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data()
    bookedTimesArray.push(...data.reservations.map((reservation) => reservation.time))
  })
  bookedTimes.value = bookedTimesArray
}

watch(date, async () => {
  await fetchBookedTimes()
})

const availableTimes = computed(() => {
  const times = []
  for (let hour = 8; hour <= 22; hour++) {
    for (let minute = 0; minute <= 30; minute += 30) {
      times.push(`${hour}:${minute.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`)
    }
  }
  return times.filter((time) => !bookedTimes.value.includes(time))
})

This is how my firestore looks like(everything is just test case)
this is also how my code looks like
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Date(Month/Day/Year):</label>
            <input type="date" v-model="date" :min="currentDate" name="Date" required />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Time:</label>
            <select v-model="time" name="Time" class="time-sec" required>
              <option value="" disabled hidden>Select The time</option>
              <option v-for="time in availableTimes" :key="time" :value="time">
                {{ time }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>

import {ref} from "vue"

const date = ref('')
const time = ref('')
const bookedTimes = ref([])

const reservations = ref({})
const docId = date.value
const currentDate = ref(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10))

async function fetchBookedTimes() {
  const bookedTimesRef = doc(db, 'reservations', docId)
  const docSnapshot = await getDoc(bookedTimesRef)
  const bookedTimesArray = []
  if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
    const data = docSnapshot.data()
    bookedTimesArray.push(...data.reservations.map((reservations) => reservations.time))
  }
  bookedTimes.value = bookedTimesArray
  console.log(bookedTimesArray)
}

watch(date, async () => {
  await fetchBookedTimes()
})

const availableTimes = computed(() => {
  const times = []
  for (let hour = 8; hour <= 22; hour++) {
    for (let minute = 0; minute <= 30; minute += 30) {
      times.push(`${hour}:${minute.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`)
    }
  }
  return times.filter((time) => !bookedTimes.value.includes(time))
})

async function handleSubmit(event) {
 bookedTimes.value.push({ date: date.value, time: time.value })
  // Check if all times for the selected date are booked
  if (availableTimes.value.length === 0) {
    // Move to the next available date
    date.value = new Date(date.value).addDays(1).toISOString().split('T')[0]
    // Reset booked times for the new date
    bookedTimes.value = bookedTimes.value.filter((booking) => booking.date !== date.value)
  }

  // Create a new reservation object
  const reservationData = {
    time: time.value,
    name: name.value,
    email: email.value,
    phone: phone.value
  }

  // Add the reservation to the reservations object
  if (!reservations.value[date.value]) {
    reservations.value[date.value] = []
  }
  reservations.value[date.value].push(reservationData)

  // Log the reservations
  console.log('Reservations:', reservations.value)

const dateId = date.value
  const reservationRef = doc(collection(db, 'reservations'), dateId)

  try {
    getDoc(reservationRef).then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        // Update the existing document
        updateDoc(reservationRef, {
          reservations: [...doc.data().reservations, reservationData]
        })
      } else {
        // Create a new document
        setDoc(reservationRef, {
          reservations: [reservationData]
        })
      }
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}


